# His reason was despaired of

Tags: meaning, phrases

What is the meaning of the phrase " **his reason was despaired of** " in this context?

The young count was taken back to his hotel in such a state that **his reason was despaired of**. He was unable to be present at La Stilla’s funeral, which took place amid an immense crowd of the Neapolitan population.

Does it mean " **he lost his sanity** or **he went insane** (due to grief) " ?

Source:
http://www.tkinter.smig.net/Romania/CastleOfTheCarpathians/Chapter09.htm

Comment: It's an old fashioned way of saying he had no hope of (despaired of) regaining his senses (reason). Today, we'd say he had a bad headache.

Comment: Or maybe better to say: There was no hope left for him to recover his senses again.

Comment: Yes, but it's exaggerated language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"To despair of one's reason" is an expression that was found still in the first part of the 20th century ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=despaired+of+his+reason&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdespaired%20of%20his%20reason%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cdespaired%20of%20his%20reason%3B%2Cc0)) and that is no used much nowadays. It means "to have lost hope that someone will have a sane mind again".

In your sentence, as it is in the passive, it means that people (those concerned) had no hope that he would recover a sane mind.

Comment: Yes, it means there was no hope left that he would recover his sanity. Something like this.